# How can I access to nested objects then render them in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, javascript-objects

How can I get all `variations` of the product and render them all in a component:

JSON:

```
[
    {
       ...
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "chicken burger 2",
        "sort": 2,
        "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/categories/unnamed_tyEgUqN.jpg",
        "price": 2.0,
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "sandwiches",
            "img": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/categories/original_D3hTuRE.jpg"
        },
        "description": "chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chicken burger chick",
        "variations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "variation_category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "add ons",
                    "is_optional": true,
                    "is_selectable": false
                },
                "item": "extra cheese",
                "price": 0.1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "variation_category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "add ons",
                    "is_optional": true,
                    "is_selectable": false
                },
                "item": "double chicken",
                "price": 0.6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I maped to `varioations[0]` and I accessed to the first object only:

```
    function ProductDetailScreen(props) {
    //api
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadProductsData();
  }, []);

  const loadProductsData = async () => {
    const response = await productsApi.getProducts();
    setProductsData(response.data);
  };
  const productId = props.route.params.productId;
  const thisProduct = productsData.filter((prod) => prod.id === productId);
    
  const thisVariation = thisProduct.map(v => v.variations[0])
  const showVar = thisVariation.map(v => v.item)
    return (
    ...
            <MyText>{showVar}</MyText>
    ...
    )
```

My question is how to get all the variations and render them in MyText, so the output will be:

```
extra cheese 0.100
double chicken 0.600
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
const variations = thisProduct.map(product => product.variations.map(variation => variation.item))
return variations.map((variation, index) => <MyText key={index}>{variation}</MyText>)
```

Comment: but, how I can render them vertically?

Comment: I think that how to render them vertically is out of scope here. I suggest you to search for similar questions, I'm sure that you will find what you Need.